# Background transition not working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css

I have been looking for a solution to this everywhere but can't seem to make it work...
I am changing a background image through JS, and i want it to fade while changing. It works flawlessly on Chrome & Edge, but Firefox has none of it.

Here is the code i'm using :

```js
document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/bg1.png')";
```

```css
#main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 919px;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background 1s linear;
    transition: background 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">blabla</div>
```

I tried using background: none;  in the css or something else, but still nothing... other threads don't seem to have the solution either on google. I'm at loss in this situation.

Comment: Did you check the browser cache?

Comment: @mohammad I did CTRL+F5 if that's what you meant, i'm using Visual Studio's Live Share to preview instantly the website. It works on Chrome and Edge, only Firefox poses an issue :(

Comment: mabye press shift + the reload icon - that clears cache and reloads the page (on firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if your aim is that when the page is loaded or reloaded the background  image is shown with a fade effect, I changed the javascript and css codes like below:

```js
let mainElem = document.getElementById("main");

function showBack() {
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    mainElem.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 1000)

 }
```

```css
#main {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 919px;
    background-image: url('04.jpg');
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <button onclick="showBack()">click me</button>
   
      <div id="main">
        blabla
      </div>
    
    
    <script src="javacode.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> I used the setTimeout javascript method that runs the function after 1s. and because you want to have a fade effect it is necessary to add "opacity:0" to your stylesheet and transition. then in the js code you only change the opacity from 0 to 1. you need to "replace" your image url in the css code.

> here is a link for better understanding of setTimeout method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the code, i didn't know about this! Sadly, my current code is for a one-page application and the background is supposed to change when clicking a button (which changes a section) so it doesn't reload the page :(

Comment: it is not very hard, you only need to add a button to your html and call a function when the button is clicked. I updated the last code to do that.